# Accessing UNC file share with credentials in Perl

Tags: perl, unc

I am trying to get a Perl scripts to access a file over UNC path using specified credentials.  Is this possible?  If not with Perl, what else could I use?

Thanks

-Jesse

Comment: FWIW UNC paths work fine in my perl scripts so long as I can access the UNC path in explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to access many varied paths with differing credentials or just one?

As non-programming solution can you map the network share to a drive letter permananently in Windows before running your perl program?

Comment: I have one set of credentials that can access all resources.   I would like to keep away from mapping a network share to access the file though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the module [Win32::NetResource](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-NetResource/NetResource.pm) it has methods to allow you to connect to Windows network resources, such as drive shares and supply the credentials.

> AddConnection(\%NETRESOURCE,$Password,$UserName,$Connection)
>
> ```
> Makes a connection to a network resource specified by %NETRESOURCE
> ```